# Sorting my API data numerically (0-9) in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have data mapped from an API (see below) which I am reaching fine but I am looking at sorting it numerically (0-9). I'm having a hard time doing this with Vue. If I had my data static in the `data(){...}`, I can get it done a number of ways. But not from an API because I can't point to the API for some reason whenever I try to point to it from a function in my methods. I have no idea what is going on and I'm hoping you guys have some direction.

The template - Because of the nesting of the API, I am nesting loops as well. (maybe there is a better way to also do this. I'm all ears). `allBatches` is my Getter. I am serving the API through my State Manager (Vuex)

```
<div>
  <div v-for="batches in allBatches" :key="batches.id">
     <div 
        v-for="dispatchstation in batches.dispatchstation" 
        :key="dispatchstation.id">
        <div v-for="apps in dispatchstation.applications" :key="apps.id">
          <div>{{apps}}</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The data structure in the API - I intentionally left unrelated data out. There are other layers in between. But this shows the path I am looping and reaching out to.

```
"batches": [
{
  "dispatchstation": [
    {
      "applications": [
        "384752387450",
        "456345634563",
        "345634563456",
        "567845362334",
        "567456745677",
        "456734562457",
        "789676545365",
        "456456445556",
        "224563456345",
        "456878656467",
        "053452345344",
        "045440545455",
        "045454545204",
        "000014546546",
        "032116876846",
        "546521302151",
        "035649874877",
        "986765151231",
        "653468463854",
        "653853121324",
        "000145456555"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

],

I've tried to do this with lodash using `_.orderBy` and use it a pipe. No luck. And I also tried this:

```
data() {
  return {
    sortAsc: true,
    sortApps: "" // see explanation
  };
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["allBatches"]),
  sortedData() {
    let result = this.sortApps;

    let ascDesc = this.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
    return result.sort(
      (a, b) => ascDesc * a.applications.localeCompare(b.applications)
    );
  }
},
```

I used (tried) this method by giving sortApps the loop criteria `dispatchstations.applications` and loop `v-for='apps in sortedData'`. I'm sure that is wrong. Vue is not really my forte.

I really don't have any preference on how this should be as long as the data renders sorted out numerically ASC.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

EDIT

Using Chase's answer, I am still getting the data through but it doesn't display. I had to remove the negation (`!`).

Mutation and getters of State view from the vue chrome tool

[image: Mutation of State view from the vue chrome tool]

[image]

EDIT 2 - A simplified version of my store module

```
  import axios from "axios";

  const state = {
    batches: [],
  };

  const getters = {
    allBatches: state => {
      return state.batches;
    },
  };

  const actions = {
    async fetchBatches({ commit }) {
      const response = await axios.get(`${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:4000/batches`);

      commit("setBatches", response.data);
    },
  };

  const mutations = {
    setBatches: (state, batches) => (state.batches = batches),
  };

  export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
  };
```

Comment: Do you want to sort all of your *applications* , or in every *dispatchstation* ?

Comment: @VoKimNguyen Great question! Just in every dispatch station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood your question, so you just need to order the data to render it and you don't need it as ordered in your store?

to display orderd data you can use this computed function, I hope it will help you

```
computed:{

      ...mapGetters(["allBatches"]),

      orderApplications(){

        let copieBatches = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allBatches));

        copieBatches.forEach(batches => {

          batches.dispatchstation.forEach(dispatchstation=>{

            dispatchstation.applications.sort()

          })

        });

        return copieBatches
      }
}
```

and your HTML will be like

```
<div>
   <div v-for="batches in orderApplications">
      <div
         v-for="dispatchstation in batches.dispatchstation"
         :key="dispatchstation.id">
             <div v-for="apps in dispatchstation.applications">
                <div>{{apps}}</div>
              </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to be sorted in an ascending order. This just brings back my data the same order is in my json.

Comment: that's strange because I used the same code and I received the data sorted, 
I repoduced it in sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/order-data-from-api-jbi4f

Comment: Thanks Daly, I just realized that I didn't update the first loop. However, now I am getting an error that breaks the UI. `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"` at this line `dispatchstation.applications.sort();`

Comment: Not sure if it's worth mentioning, that I am using a setter in my mutations to populate the response coming back from my API in my actions. I will update my question with a simplified copy of my store module

Comment: that's because maybe in some dispatchapplications you don't have the property applications, so just add 

    `  if(dispatchstation.hasOwnProperty('applications')) `
before 
dispatchstation.applications.sort() 
 I hope it will work :)

Comment: DUDE! I would kiss you right now!!! hahaha Thanks a lot man. Being the only front dev here sucks. SO won't let me award you the bounty until 12 hrs have passed. But trust me, they're yours

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding your question, but essentially I would recommend loading your data in the same way that you are currently and handling the sort in a computed method.

This is assuming that the length of batches and dispatchstation will always be 1.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    allBatches: null
  },
  computed: {
    batchesSorted() {
      if (!this.allBatches) return {}
      
      const output = this.allBatches.batches[0].dispatchstation[0].applications;

      output.sort((a, b) => {
        return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)
      })

      return output
    }
  },
  async created() {
    // Equivelent to ...mapGetters(["allBatches"]) for the example
    this.allBatches = {
      "batches": [{
        "dispatchstation": [{
          "applications": [
            "384752387450",
            "456345634563",
            "345634563456",
            "567845362334",
            "567456745677",
            "456734562457",
            "789676545365",
            "456456445556",
            "224563456345",
            "456878656467",
            "053452345344",
            "045440545455",
            "045454545204",
            "000014546546",
            "032116876846",
            "546521302151",
            "035649874877",
            "986765151231",
            "653468463854",
            "653853121324",
            "000145456555"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, key) in batchesSorted" :key="key">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I misunderstood anything or if you have any questions.

Comment: `The computed property "allBatches" is already defined in data.` It's conflicting with the computed `...mapGettters(["allBatches"])`, which I need for state management purposes

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this outside of the code, but you can use your getter in place of importing the data in the `created` hook. I was just using that to get the data into the component for the example.

Comment: oh yeah, I was. I figured that. It was referrring to the data value and condition evaluation in computed. I changed these to allApps and the screen runs without errors, but the loop returns nothing.

Comment: For moving it over to your code, both the declaration and initialization of the `allBatches` property from my code can be removed. The only thing you'll need is the `...mapGetters(["allBatches"])` computed property and the `batchesSorted` computed property.

Comment: On this line `const output = this.allBatches.batches[0].dispatchstation[0].applications;`

Comment: But if I remove the negation `if (this.allBatches) return {};` then the errors go away, but nothing comes back in the screen

Comment: I edited my answer with the data coming through. but no display